# Add rows if missing recent data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which contains some numbers with dates and country information:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"day": ['2021-01-01', '2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03'],
                        "country": ["France", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Cuba", "France"],
                        "n": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    })
```

This looks like:

```
          day country  n
0  2021-01-01  France  1
1  2021-01-01  Brazil  2
2  2021-01-02  Brazil  3
3  2021-01-02    Cuba  4
4  2021-01-03  France  5
```

I'd like to compute some statistics to monitor if the data I received on the 2021-01-03 contain some errors, and for this I need to compare the data I got on the 3rd Jan. to the mean (for example) of the previous data.

So I'd like to add some rows which would indicate that I got nothing on the 3rd Jan for Brazil and Cuba, this is the output I'd like:

```
  country         day    n
0  France  2021-01-03  5.0
1  France  2021-01-01  1.0
2  Brazil  2021-01-01  2.0
3  Brazil  2021-01-02  3.0
4    Cuba  2021-01-02  4.0
5  Brazil  2021-01-03  NaN
6    Cuba  2021-01-03  NaN
```

Here is the code I tried but I does not feel very "pandas-like", I believe there is a built-in in Pandas or at least a better way of adding data for recent rows:

```
countries = pd.DataFrame({"country": df.country.unique()})
recent_date = pd.DataFrame({"day":[df.day.max()]})
countries.merge(recent_date, how="cross").merge(df, how="outer")
```

This is the result:

```
 country         day    n
0  France  2021-01-03  5.0
1  Brazil  2021-01-03  NaN
2    Cuba  2021-01-03  NaN
3  France  2021-01-01  1.0
4  Brazil  2021-01-01  2.0
5  Brazil  2021-01-02  3.0
6    Cuba  2021-01-02  4.0
```

(PS: I'm open to suggestions on the title of this post)

Comment: Answer was edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is filter out all unique countries which has no maximal day and add to original with [`numpy.setdiff1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html):

```
d = df.day.max()
c = np.setdiff1d(df.country.unique(), df.loc[df['day'].eq(d), 'country'])

df = df.append(pd.DataFrame({'country':c, 'day': d}), ignore_index=True)
print (df)
         day country    n
0 2021-01-01  France  1.0
1 2021-01-01  Brazil  2.0
2 2021-01-02  Brazil  3.0
3 2021-01-02    Cuba  4.0
4 2021-01-03  France  5.0
5 2021-01-03  Brazil  NaN
6 2021-01-03    Cuba  NaN
```

First idea, a bit complicated:

```
df['day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['day'] )

c = df.loc[df['day'].eq(df['day'].max()), 'country']

df = df.append(df[['country']].drop_duplicates()
                              .assign(day = df['day'].max())
                              .query("country not in @c"), ignore_index=True)
print (df)
         day country    n
0 2021-01-01  France  1.0
1 2021-01-01  Brazil  2.0
2 2021-01-02  Brazil  3.0
3 2021-01-02    Cuba  4.0
4 2021-01-03  France  5.0
5 2021-01-03  Brazil  NaN
6 2021-01-03    Cuba  NaN
```